# Should I use Canvas or GWTCanvas?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

I'm creating a canvas with GWT, and I have seen both solutions using `Canvas.createIfSupported();` or `new GWTCanvas();`

Which one is the preferred, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Canvas`.  It's part of GWT.  `GWTCanvas` is only in the incubator project, which is deprecated now.